# How do I select the user_ids that transacted consecutively in the last 3 years from this table?

Tags: mysql, sql

The table is very simple, it has only 2 columns - user_id and date.
What I want to do is select all the user_ids that have transacted in 2020 AND 2019 AND 2018.

I have no idea how to do this, I tried to make a table with user_ids that transacted in 2020 and joined it with people who transacted in 2019, and then join that with a table where people transacted in 2018.

Here's the code:

```
select DISTINCT(user_id) 
  from (
          (
            ( SELECT t1.user_id
              FROM table as t1
              WHERE EXTRACT( YEAR FROM date) = 2020
            ) as flag_2020 
    
          JOIN 
           
          (
             SELECT t2.user_id
              FROM table as t2
              WHERE EXTRACT( YEAR FROM date) = 2019
           ) as flag_2019 
    
          ON flag_2019.user_id = flag_2020.user_id
    
        )  as tab2
    
    JOIN 
       
       ( SELECT t3.user_id
              FROM table as t3
              WHERE EXTRACT( YEAR FROM date) = 2018
        ) as flag_2018 
           
        ON tab2.user_id= flag_2018.user_id 
     )
```

This doesn't work and gives a check syntax error near 'tab2 JOIN' line.
I don't know what/how to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to do is select all the user_ids that have transacted in 2020 AND 2019 AND 2018.

A simple method uses aggregation:

```
select user_id
from (select distinct user_id, year(date) as yyyy
      from t
      where date >= '2018-01-01' and
            date < '2021-01-01'
     ) uy
group by user_id
having count(*) = 3;
```

The subquery returns one row per `user_id` and year in the range you specify.  The outer query returns all user ids that have all three rows.

You don't actually need the subquery.  I just think the logic is easier to follow that way:

```
select user_id
from t
where date >= '2018-01-01' and
      date < '2021-01-01'
group by user_id
having count(distinct year(date)) = 3;
```

Comment: I am trying to understand your query [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ee077/28) can you please explain why we get only id = 1 when we uncomment the last line having count > 0 ?